# Error, Estas filas exceden los límites al eliminar una fila en googlespreadsheet con javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Hola estoy intentando eliminar unas filas que no son iguales a los de otra hoja y todo perfecto hasta llegar a la hora de eliminarlas ya que me dice que estas filas exceden los limites. No se porque motivo me esta saliendo este error.

Os dejo el código a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

```
function myFunction() {
function Lento() {
    var h1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
    var h2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 2');
    var rowsh1 = h1.getDataRange();
    var valuesh1 = rowsh1.getValues();
    var numColsh1 = rowsh1.getNumColumns();
    var numRowsh1 = rowsh1.getNumRows();
    var rowsh2 = h2.getDataRange();
    var valuesh2 = rowsh2.getValues();
    var numColsh2 = rowsh2.getNumColumns();
    var numRowsh2 = rowsh2.getNumRows();
  var idusuario = [];
  var identificador = [];
  //recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja1
   for (var r=1; r<valuesh2.length; r++) {
        var rowh2 = valuesh2[r],
            nombre = rowh2[1],
            email = rowh2[2],
            telefono = rowh2[3],
            mensaje = rowh2[4],
            urllanding = rowh2[5],
            fechausuario = rowh2[6];
           idusuario[r] = rowh2[0];//Guardamos los gclid del usuario en un array

           }
  //recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja2
    for (var r=1; r<valuesh1.length; r++) {
        var rowh1 = valuesh1[r],
            palabraclave = rowh1[1],
            ciudad = rowh1[2],
            fecha = rowh1[4],
            pais = rowh1[5];
      identificador[r] = rowh1[0];//Guardamos los gclid en un array

           }

  for (var i=1;i<identificador.length;i++) 
  { 
    for (var y=1;y<idusuario.length;y++) 
    { 
      if (identificador[i] != idusuario[y]) 
      { 
         h1.deleteRow(i+1);
      } 
    } 
  } 

}

Lento();
}
```

Comment: En todos los links que he encontrado ponen un `+1` en el `deleteRow`, prueba utilizando `h1.deleteRow(i+1);` ya que tiene pinta que el índice interno ufnciona distinto (partiendo de `1`)

Comment: Lo he probado y no me funciona bien, ya que es como si eliminara lo que el quisiera. ya que en la hoja1 me quedan unos id los cuales no estan en la hoja 2 y no deberia de funcionar asi

Comment: Puede ser también que estés eliminando varias veces la misma fila (y eso provoca problemas). Y si guardas los IDs que vas eliminando en otra lista y lo añades en la condición del IF?

Comment: me podrías echar un cable? como puedo hacer eso, como puedo saber que estoy eliminando la misma fila?

Comment: Con este codigo `for (var i=0;i<identificador.length;i++) 
  { 
    for (var y=0;y<idusuario.length;y++) 
    { 
      if (identificador[i] != idusuario[y]) 
      { 
         h1.deleteRow(i);
      } 
    } 
  }` compruebo el primer resultado de la hoja 1 con todos los valores de la hoja2 no?

Comment: voy a publicar una respuesta idicando cosas que podrías hacer, ya que en los comentarios es complicado y creo que no tienes acceso al chat --> http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol (si tienes acceso al link di hola o algo y hablamos por ahí).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error lo tienes en la comparación **dentro** de tu segundo `for`. Al hacer la comparación ahí dentro todos los elementos se acaban eliminando por lo que se tiene que trasladar fuera del segundo `for`.

Asimismo el `deleteRow(id)` funciona con identificador partiendo de `0` por lo que se le tiene que sumar `+1` al `id` al que se referencia.

Esta es la solución final:

```
function myFunction() {
    function Lento() {
        var h1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
        var h2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 2');
        var rowsh1 = h1.getDataRange();
        var valuesh1 = rowsh1.getValues();
        var numColsh1 = rowsh1.getNumColumns();
        var numRowsh1 = rowsh1.getNumRows();
        var rowsh2 = h2.getDataRange();
        var valuesh2 = rowsh2.getValues();
        var numColsh2 = rowsh2.getNumColumns();
        var numRowsh2 = rowsh2.getNumRows();
        var idusuario = [];
        var identificador = [];
        //recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja1 
        for (var r = 1; r < valuesh2.length; r++) {
            var rowh2 = valuesh2[r],
                nombre = rowh2[1],
                email = rowh2[2],
                telefono = rowh2[3],
                mensaje = rowh2[4],
                urllanding = rowh2[5],
                fechausuario = rowh2[6];
            idusuario[r] = rowh2[0]; //Guardamos los gclid del usuario en un array 

        }
        //recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja2 
        for (var r = 1; r < valuesh1.length; r++) {
            var rowh1 = valuesh1[r],
                palabraclave = rowh1[1],
                ciudad = rowh1[2],
                fecha = rowh1[4],
                pais = rowh1[5];
            identificador[r] = rowh1[0]; //Guardamos los gclid en un array 

        }


        for (var i = identificador.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var encontrado = false;
            for (var y = 1; y < idusuario.length; y++) {

                if (identificador[i] == null || idusuario[y] == null) continue;
                if (identificador[i] == idusuario[y]) {
                    encontrado = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!encontrado) {

                h1.deleteRow(i + 1);
            }
        }

    }

    Lento();
}
```

Los cambios son:

Se ha añadido un `bool` que indica si se ha encontrado el elemento de la `Hoja 1` (primer bucle `for`) en la `Hoja 2` (segundo bucle `for`). Si el elemento **no** se ha encontrado se elimina (sumando `+1` al `deleteRow`).

También se comprueba dentro del segundo bucle si alguna de las variables es `null` ya que el compoartamiento de javascript con los `null` es... *raro*. Al añadir las condiciones de `if (identificador[i] == null || idusuario[y] == null) continue;` básicamente pasamos a la siguiente iteración del bucle con el `continue`.

Se ha añadido un `break` para optimizar el segundo bucle ya que si se encuentra el elemento no hace falta continuar y el `break` termina el bucle en ese instante sin que requiera su iteración completa.

Comment: Gracias Miquel por la ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Hola me vuelve a dar el mismo error pero ahora en otra linea y esto no se el porque?

Comment: @AitorUdabe mmmm creo que es mejor publiques una nueva pregunta y lo miramos.

Comment: Vale perfecto si porque tengo otra pregunta que hacerte

Comment: Miquel aqui tienes el enlace a la otra pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26935/error-de-estas-filas-exceden-los-l%C3%ADmites-en-google-sheet