# Error "Estas filas estás fuera de los límites"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

El mensaje de error es `Estas filas exceden los límites. (línea 138, archivo "Código")` y en la fila 138 esta esta linea de código:

```
hoja1.deleteRows(2,datoshoja1.length);
```

El problema, tengo el mismo codigo en un sheet de pruebas y ahi funciona correctamente.

A continuación el código completo:

```
function myFunction() { 
function Lento() { 
var h1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 1'); 
var h2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 2'); 
var rowsh1 = h1.getDataRange(); 
var valuesh1 = rowsh1.getValues(); 
var numColsh1 = rowsh1.getNumColumns(); 
var numRowsh1 = rowsh1.getNumRows(); 
var rowsh2 = h2.getDataRange(); 
var valuesh2 = rowsh2.getValues(); 
var numColsh2 = rowsh2.getNumColumns(); 
var numRowsh2 = rowsh2.getNumRows(); 
var idusuario = []; 
var identificador = []; 
//recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja1 
for (var r=1; r<valuesh2.length; r++) { 
var rowh2 = valuesh2[r], 
nombre = rowh2[1], 
email = rowh2[2], 
telefono = rowh2[3], 
mensaje = rowh2[4], 
urllanding = rowh2[5], 
fechausuario = rowh2[6]; 
idusuario[r] = rowh2[0];//Guardamos los gclid del usuario en un array 

} 
//recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja2 
for (var r=1; r<valuesh1.length; r++) { 
var rowh1 = valuesh1[r], 
palabraclave = rowh1[3], 
grupo = rowh1[1], 
camp=rowh1[2], 
disp=rowh1[4], 
fecha = rowh1[5]; 
identificador[r] = rowh1[0];//Guardamos los gclid en un array 

} 


for (var i=identificador.length-1;i>0;i--) 
{ 
var encontrado = false; 
for (var y=1;y<idusuario.length;y++) 
{ 

if (identificador[i]== null || idusuario[y] == null) continue; 
if (identificador[i] == idusuario[y]) 
{ 
Logger.log("encontramos el " + i); 
Logger.log("identificador " + identificador[i]); 
Logger.log("idusuario " + idusuario[y]); 
encontrado = true; 
break; 
} 
} 

if (!encontrado) { 

Logger.log("eliminamos el " + i); 
h1.deleteRow(i+1); 
} 
} 

} 

Lento(); 
function Exportar() {

var spreadsheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BB0vMBQNfNI9mMUMmgvU_aC3KkDf-Uic0JjeKE5-ClY");
var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14ilkiECtg4lRoLxZBVfFXnoYFISAuQ2-dDIoxOz3qXc");
var hoja1 = spreadsheet1.getSheetByName("Hoja 1"); //Nombre de las hoja 1
var hoja2 = spreadsheet1.getSheetByName("Hoja 2"); //Nombre de la hoja 2
var datoshoja1 = hoja1.getDataRange().getValues();
var datoshoja2 = hoja2.getDataRange().getValues();
var nombre =[];
var email =[];
var telefono =[];
var mensaje =[];
var urllanding =[];
var fechausuario =[];
var idusuario =[];
var adgroup =[] ;
var campania=[];
var palabraclave =[]; 
var dispositivo =[]; 
var fecha =[] ;
//var pais = []; 
var identificador =[] ;
var hoja1sheet2 = spreadsheet2.getSheetByName("DatosReporteUsuario");  
var datoshoja2sheet2=hoja1sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
var posicionsumar=datoshoja2sheet2.length;
Logger.log("Registros hoja2 " + posicionsumar); 

for(var i=0; i<datoshoja1.length; i++){ 
var rowh1 = datoshoja1[i]; 
adgroup[i] = rowh1[1];
campania[i] = rowh1[2]; 
palabraclave[i] = rowh1[3]; 
dispositivo[i] = rowh1[4]; 
fecha[i] = rowh1[5]; 
identificador[i] = rowh1[0];
}

for(var i=1; i<datoshoja1.length; i++){
hoja1sheet2.getRange('A'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(fecha[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('G'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(dispositivo[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('H'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(campania[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('I'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(adgroup[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('J'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(palabraclave[i]);



//hoja1.getRange(2, 1, nuevosvalores.length, hoja1.getLastColumn()).setValues(nuevosvalores);

}
for(var i=0; i<datoshoja2.length; i++){ 
var rowh2 = datoshoja2[i]; 
nombre[i] = rowh2[1];
email[i] = rowh2[2]; 
telefono[i] = rowh2[3]; 
mensaje[i] = rowh2[4]; 
urllanding[i] = rowh2[5]; 
fechausuario[i] = rowh2[6]; 
idusuario[i] = rowh2[0];
}

for(var i=1; i<datoshoja2.length; i++){
hoja1sheet2.getRange('B'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(nombre[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('C'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(email[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('D'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(telefono[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('E'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(mensaje[i]);
hoja1sheet2.getRange('K'+(posicionsumar+i)).setValue(urllanding[i]);


//hoja1.getRange(2, 1, nuevosvalores.length,       hoja1.getLastColumn()).setValues(nuevosvalores);

}
hoja1.deleteRows(2,datoshoja1.length);
hoja2.deleteRows(2,posicionsumar);
}
Exportar();
}
```

Comment: Hoy ha hecho la modificación y no me ha dado ningun error. probaremos dos días más a ver que sucede

Comment: Me ha vuelto a dar error hoy mismo y no entiendo el porque?

Comment: ¿Cuál es mensaje de error? ¿Has revisado la transcripción de la ejecución? Favor de ver [mcve] y https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting

Comment: Hola no no he visto la transcipcion pero el mensaje de error es el que he indico `Estas filas exceden los límites. (línea 138, archivo "Código")` y en la fila 138 esta esta linea de codigo `hoja1.deleteRows(2,datoshoja1.length);` A si que no se que puede ser

Comment: Alguien puede ayudarme en este error? no entiendo porque en el sheet de pruebas funciona bien y en el que tengo todo no.

Comment: Las preguntas que tienen mejor redacción tienen mayores posibilidades de ser respondidas rápido, por ello te dejé el enlace a [mcve]. El código que has dejado tiene muchas líneas que no son necesarias para reproducir el error pero que hacen que el código exceda el espacio disponible y aparezcan la barras de desplazamiento vertical. Así mismo, es preferible que acortes tus líneas de código para que no aparezca la barra de desplazamiento horizontal.

Comment: Sobre el mensaje de error, es posible que datoshoja1.lenght sea mayour al número de filas disponibles. ¿Ya revisaste eso?

Comment: yo lo que quiero hacer es eliminar todos los valores de la hoja 1 menos la cabecera, no lo he comprobado porque teoriamente esta bien ya que en el sheet de pruebas funciona bien,Y tambien quiero hacer que si el id esta repetido en la hoja2 eliminarlo en vez de ponerlo porque eso tambien me pasa

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Reemplaza

```
hoja1.deleteRows(2,datoshoja1.length)
```

por

```
hoja1.deleteRows(2,datoshoja1.length-1)
```

## Explicación

El error ocurre seguramente porque el número de filas de datoshoja1 es el mismo que el número de filas de la hoja.

Comment: Vale lo probare, mañana cuando sepa si funciona os lo comunico pero tiene buena pinta